# newcomputermodern and def command

Tags: xetex, newcomputermodern

Consider the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{newcomputermodern}
\def\phi{\varphi}
\begin{document}
$$ \phi $$
\end{document}
```

As a result, the code will create a document with `varphi`, but if I uncomment the second line, then the document will contain the letter `phi`.

If I try a number of other `def`s, they won't work either. Can't figure out what the problem is and how to fix it.

Comment: newcomputermodern loads unicode-math which redefine \phi at begin document. You can use `\AtBeginDocument{\def\phi{\varphi}}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newcomputermodern}
\begin{document}
\def\phi{\varphi}
$$\phi$$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Avoid `\def` as much as possible (here `\renewcommand` is the good tool) and never use `$$` in LaTeX.

Comment: On this site, a minimal example is preferable